# Password Protecting Web Directories and Files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

A user enters my website and arrives at the home page, he/she should always and only be at home page. All other files are scripts that are run by the homepage but the user should never navigate to them. So here's my directory layout:
[image: Directory]

They will arrive at Front.php and should **always** stay at Front. So I created an htaccess file that has this code:

```
DirectoryIndex Front.php index.html
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /disks/*/*/*/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Right now, **EVERYTHING** requires authentication. But I want everything **except** Front.php to require authentication. How can I exclude Front.php from the authentication?

Also, will this authentication prevent the scripts from running or does it just prevent the user from navigating *TO* the file via url?

Answer (score 2):

> Right now, EVERYTHING requires authentication. But I want everything except Front.php to require authentication. How can I exclude Front.php from the authentication?

Try:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/Front.php norequire_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /disks/*/*/*/.htpasswd

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is set
Allow from env=norequire_auth
```

This uses the `Satisfy` directive and sets it to *`any`*, meaning either the `Require valid-user` or the `Allow` is good enough. The variable `norequire_auth` only gets set when the URI is `/Front.php`. You can add additional whitelisted URI's if you want by including additional `SetEnvIfNoCase` directives.

> Also, will this authentication prevent the scripts from running or does it just prevent the user from navigating TO the file via url?

It won't prevent the scripts from running, if you include them via a `include` or `require`. But if you *directly link* to them from `Front.php`'s HTML content, the login dialog will pop up for Front.php.

Comment: You are wise in the ways of access!

Comment: @JonLin So this is what my htaccess file looks like now: [htaccess](http://pastie.org/5046709). But when I navigate to `www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php` it stills requires authentication. Any ideas why?

Comment: @CharlieYabben well, if `/Folder/Front.php` is the one you want to exclude, then you need to put that in `SetEnvIfNoCase`'s regular expression. i.e. `^/Folder/Front.php`

Comment: @JonLin Oh so does this go in the root directory? The directory image I'm showing in my post is just 1 folder in a larger directory, it is `www.domain.com/Folder`

Comment: @CharlieYabben No, the htaccess file goes into the directory you want to protect, but the `Request_URI` is going to be everything after the hostname in the URL, so everything after `http://www.domain.com`

Comment: @JonLin okay good, so here's my updated [htaccess](http://pastie.org/5046709) but it's the same problem as before. When i try to navigate to the page, `www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php` it still wants authentication

Comment: @CharlieYabben ***`Allow from env=norequire_auths`***, is that "s" supposed to be there or is it a typo?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17954/discussion-between-charlie-yabben-and-jon-lin)

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't want to be able to enter other scripts, but you add authentication to it.

If you don't want to execute those scripts directly, it's better to move them out of the public_html folder, so they cannot be reached from outside at all. You will still be able to include/require them in front.php.

Admin scripts can easily be moved to a subdirectory on which you can add authentication from .htaccess. If you want to add authentication to some files, but not all, you can also choose to send the required headers from the PHP scripts.

You often see a check like this at the start of a file:

```
defined('MYAPPDEFINE') || die('No direct access allowed');
```

In the entry page (index.php, front.php, whatever), you can add this line:

```
define('MYAPPDEFINE', 'Whatever value');
```

This way, every file that is called directly will die and terminate immediately, but when it is included from front.php, the check succeeds and the file is included.

Comment: Just trying to wrap my head around this. So if I add authentication to a file, such as Insert.php. Then when Front.php calls it, will it not respond if you don't have authentication?

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious: organization is worth a thousand lines of code! @CharlieYabben What does "calls it" mean? If they are included or required, they will not require authentication. But if they are in an .htaccess protected directory, and visited via HTTP they would trigger a login request.

Comment: Yes it will, but you could do that for file that are entry files for admin pages. Pages that are not entries at all should not be able to be called directly. Preferably move them up a directory so they cannot be reached through an uri, and/or just let them `die` (added an extra paragraph to the answer about that).

Answer (score 0):

Use this ruleset:

```
<Filesmatch "^((?!Front\.php).)*$">
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /disks/*/*/*/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</Filesmatch>

<Files "Front.php">
allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Append it to the existing .htaccess file (put it at the bottom)? Tried that it still wants authentication to access Front.php

Comment: @CharlieYabben: I have updated my answer. You need to specify the password rule for all files **other than** Front.php. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @CharlieYabben: Strange because it works for me. Front.php runs without auth and for every other file it asks me for a username/password..

Comment: is there something I should put before/after this? I'm running on an apache server so any settings I have to enable?

Comment: check if httpd.conf allows .htaccess overrides. Also, did you say that right now ALL files are being password protected?

Comment: I cant actually check that...i'm just creating a website for an organization and I don't have admin access to their webserver. But this is what my htaccess file looks like now: [pastie](http://pastie.org/5047669). And yes everything is protected. I can't access a single thing (files, folders) without the auth

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17957/discussion-between-charlie-yabben-and-raidenace)

Answer (score 0):

Use this .htaccess content to prevent people from requesting anything but front.php:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !front.php [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Now only fron.php will be available to anyone accessing your apache.

BTW - as far as I know - you can force Apache to authenticate anything in particular directory but not not single files.

Comment: for some reason this is blocking access to all files including Front.php. Did you mean to say `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !Front.php [NC]`?

Comment: @Charlie: Actually [NC] flag says NoCase which means that access will be forbidden to any files but FRONT.PHP, FrONT.pHP etc regardless of case. I've checked these lines and they are working fine. If not working for you - block your other rule creating .htaccess with only these 3 lines first for tests.